# MongoDb - count posts before, during and after given period

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i have a collection "posts". Each post have a publication date. I have two dates (period) - start_date and end_date. I want to aggregate this collection (with additional conditions, like published = true), and retrieve 3 values:
- before_count (number of posts before that period)
- during count (number of posts during that period)
- after_count (number of posts after that period)

How can i do that? I'm not very familiar with MongoDb - i know how to do it with 3 queries, but i'm pretty sure it can be done with only 1 query.

Comment: Show your 3 queries to start with. What kind of answer you expect without providing any examples of documents you are querying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a single query that uses the aggregate operation where your initial pipeline step comprises of a **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** step to filter the documents getting into the pipeline and a subsequent **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** stage to group all the documents as a whole (with `_id` null) and then use the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator to create the logic for getting the counts in different periods to feed the **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** accumulator.

Take for instance the following example:

```
db.posts.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "publication_date": { "$exists": true }, "published": true } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "before_count": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$lt": ["$publication_date", start_date] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },
            "during_count": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [
                        {
                            "$and": [
                                { "$gte": ["$publication_date", start_date] },
                                { "$lte": ["$publication_date", end_date] },
                            ]
                        },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },
            "after_count": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$gt": ["$publication_date", end_date] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thank you very much @chridam, thats exactly what i was looking for!